# Dissapear on click with cookie

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

How do i have this code have a set cookie that makes it not appear again after visit another page and go back to it??? See live version at onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx

Also see where i got the code  [here](http://brockangelo.com/2009/06/19/replace-text-on-click-using-javascript/)

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

function toggle_text(shown, hidden) {
       var e = document.getElementById(shown);
       var f = document.getElementById(hidden);
    if(e.style.display == 'inline') {
                  e.style.display = 'none';
                  f.style.display = 'inline';
      }
      else {
                  e.style.display = 'inline';
                  f.style.display = 'none';
      }
}
</script>
    <div id="shown_first" style="display:inline">
      <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="toggle_text('shown_first', 'hidden_first')">
      <a href="/popular.html" style="text-decoration:none;"><i> New! </i> Vote for Websites Here</a.
      </a>
</div>
<div id="hidden_first" style="display:none">
      <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="toggle_text('shown_first', 'hidden_first')">

      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: _“How do i have this code have a set cookie”_ – by doing some _research_ on that topic first …?

Comment: cbroe i dont have time for that

Comment: No one _cares_ if you are under any time pressure. If you went in over your head with an assignment, that is purely and solely _your_ problem.

Comment: this isnt an assignment. i just need this figured out quickly. and since your not even helping why are you even talking to me.

Comment: SO is not a site for people to just “get the answer quickly” without showing any own effort.

Comment: what i use this site for isn't for you to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to tie an event into the window.onunload() event that removes whatever cookie you're looking for.

Html -

```
<body onunload="deleteCookie()">
```

JavaScript -

```
window.onunload=function(){
    // Get cookie
    // Set cookie expiration to yesterday
};
```

When the page closes it will call the onunload event.  In that event, you'll get the cookie you're looking for and then set the value to yesterday so the cookie will expire and be removed from the browser.

Comment: do i just copy paste that into my code? because when i did that it didnt work... The text stayed there when  went back to the home page.

Comment: Where it says get cookie and set cookie.... add this code
document.cookie = "yourcookiename=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
That will get the cookie yourcookiename and set the date to an expired date.  Taken right from the w3schools website.  
Will you mark this correct if it works for you?